# крестики-нолики неудачно спроектированы

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода, backbone.js

сделал на backbone простейшую версию крестиков-ноликов:

http://fh79272k.bget.ru/files/works/tic_tac_toe/1/

https://github.com/zlodiak/ttt_1

но есть сомнения по поводу выбранной архитектуры(если так можно её назвать). основной класс APP.TttView содержит слишком много методов и при том длинных. а это верный признак, что программа спроектирована наудачно

игра состоит из нескольких view:

```
APP.TttView       // основа игры
APP.FieldView     // генерация игрового поля
APP.CellView      // генерация клетки
```

я почти всю логику поместил в основной view:

```
    APP.TttView = Backbone.View.extend({  

      render(),         // отрисовка элементов игры

      playerStep(),     // handler хода игрока

      compStep(),       // handler хода компьютера

      addStep(),        // запись информации об очередном ходе в спец.массив

      winnerCheck()     // вызывается после каждого хода. здесь же вызывается alert в случае победы

});
```

в APP.FieldView есть метод, который проверяет сложились ли крестики или нолики в линию:

```
APP.FieldView = Backbone.View.extend({  

  checkCellLines()    // проверка расположения крестиков/ноликов

});
```

1. объясните пожалуйста хотя бы на словах как лучше организовать код? чтобы не было простыни кода
2. и ещё пожалуйста скажите, правильно ли я поступил, вынес checkCellLines() в APP.FieldView ? всё таки APP.FieldView не обязан ничего проверять, он просто отвечает за отображение поля...

Comment: Вот это и плохо — логика во View. Разделите на View и модель, по крайней мере.

Comment: Шлю багрепорт: можно выиграть и проиграть одновременно) То есть после выигрыша комп может сходить еще раз и выиграть тоже

Comment: VladD, в любом случае это проблему не решит в яваскриптовом mvc вид и представление объединены(по крайней мере в backbone этот принцип используется). в модель можно вынести какую-нибудь небольшую часть логики, связанную с обработкой или извлечением из БД данных, но основная часть логики останется в view